# Simple LinkedList no me deja agregar .add(int);

Tags: java

Estoy practicando con unos tutoriales y me surgió un problema. No puedo agregar a la lista un objeto `int`?

```
package paquete;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

    list.add("Perro");
    list.add(0, "Gato");
    list.add(5);
```

El problema está en `list.add(5);` que cuando lo ejecuto me tira este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:  The method add(int, Object) in the type LinkedList is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int)
>
> at paquete.Main.main(Main.java:14)

Ojalá me puedan ayudar!

Comment: No pude reproducir tu error, vea el [código en Ideone](https://ideone.com/KT2zxO). ¿Estás seguro que no hay nada más en tu código?

Comment: El comentario que le hice a Omar, si cambias la libreria a jre1.8.0_65 sucede el error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La cuestión con Java es que las Listas son colecciones; y las colecciones usan algo que se llama [type erasure, o generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). En pocas palabras, puedes inicializar una lista solo con tipos de una clase. En tu caso quieres agregar un `int` que es un valor primitivo, no un objeto. Lo que puedes hacer para agregar ese valor sería lo siguiente:

```
LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
Integer intToAdd = new Integer(5);
list.add(intToAdd);
```

La clase [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) funciona cómo un envoltorio para valores primitivos de tipo `int`. De esa manera pasas cómo parámetro que la lista acepta valores de tipo Object (es la clase "origen", en pocas palabras).

Comment: Gracias por la información, ahora sí funciona. Al código que me daba problemas ya me anda bien tambien, cambiando la libreria a "JavaSE-1.7" antes lo tenía en "jre1.8.0_65". Me gustaría saber por qué se pudo arreglar cambiando la librería; muchas gracias por la solución!

Comment: +1, Se  puede cambiar LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<>(); por LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>(); ya que esa sintaxis no es valida en java 6

Comment: Para las clases envoltorio de los tipos primitivos es mejor utilizar `.valueOf` en general, para permitir que la implementación se encargue, si quiere, de "cachear" objetos.  En este caso usaríamos `Integer.valueOf(5)`

Comment: O puedes usar el auto boxing y poner : `Integer intToAdd = 5;`

Comment: @jasilva eso es completamente válido si estás usando Java 6, pero en Java 7 y delante te marca una warning... las warnings son mis enemigas.

Comment: @Popplar si tu requerimiento no es usar una versión concreta de java, te recomendaría utilizar la versión más actual. En Java 8 tienes muchas ventajas entre ellas las closures. Deberías darle una segunda oportunidad :)

Comment: @Omar La verdad es que debería tener la version 8? Instale la ultima versión de Eclipse (eclipse-java-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64) y de Java (jdk-8u65-windows-x64). Debería de aparecerme JavaSE-1.8?

Comment: Ya está. Tenía que instalar el editor de Eclipse mas nuevo.

Comment: Más práctico: `list.add(Integer.valueof(5));`